# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. - context menu issues

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have issues with context menu. I am not sure why, I made similar thing many times but now I am unable to pass it. When I deleted this line:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of contextMenu">
</div>
```

Context menu works fine (but I need this line to fill my context menu.
This is part of html:

```
<mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent>
    <div *ngFor="let element of contextMenu">
    </div>
    </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

And my context menu object:

```
  @Input() contextMenu: MenuElement[];
```

And html with filled input:

```
  <lib-mp-file-explorer
          [fileElements]="fileElements | async"
          [path]="currentPath"
          [canNavigateUp]="canNavigateUp"
          [topMenu]="topMenu"
          [contextMenu]="contextMenu"
          (folderAdded)="addFolder($event)"
          (elementRemoved)="removeElement($event)"
          (navigatedDown)="navigateToFolder($event)"
          (navigatedUp)="navigateUp()"
          (elementRenamed)="renameElement($event)"
          (elementMoved)="moveElement($event)"
        >
  </lib-mp-file-explorer>
```

And my construction:

```
this.contextMenu = [
      {
        name: 'Open in Mark',
        icon: 'M',
        action: undefined,
        disabled: true
      }, 
      ...
]
```

I hate this error now:

> core.js:5828 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object
>   '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to
>   Iterables such as Arrays.

But my array is iterable T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu reference variable has the same name..

`<mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu">`

..as the array you are trying to loop through

`<div *ngFor="let element of contextMenu">`

A template reference variable is not iterable.

Try renaming your array:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of menuElements">
```

And `Input()`:

```
@Input() menuElements: MenuElement[];
```

and then

```
this.menuElements = [
 // your data
]
```

Comment: U god damn right! Thanks! You are the best player in "Where is willy?" game!

Comment: Practice makes perfect :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can check what there are actual values in your `contextMenu`:

```
<p>contextMenu {{ contextMenu | json }}
```

However, your error says that it is object, so you can use `keyvalue` pipe since Angular 6:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of contextMenu | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Pipe dosen't work. How to force him to read is as array? If i add console. log, i see whole array. Only in html problem occurs.

Comment: Sadly - pipe don't work and i can't chec directly in html actual values. Only in ts file.